# D3.js transition for set of rectangles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, visualization

Here is my problem, I want to use `transition()` method of d3.js but for a set of rectangles that I don't know the size.

For example: At first I have 2 rectangles then 3 then 4 and then 2.

Can I use `transition()` in this case? If so, what's the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well that depend, what is it you want to transition exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use invisible rectangles for providing good hover effect in charts. So while creating the rectangles I simply assign them a class. While updating I remove elements of that class first and just repeat the process.

```
tmpsvg = svg.transition();
g = tmpsvg.select('g');//prefer to refer by classname

g.selectAll(".bar-rect").remove();
var rect = g.selectAll(".bar-rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
    .attr("class", "bar-rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(d.key)-10; })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", "20px")
    .attr("height", h)
    .on("mouseenter", function(d, i) {
       //TOOLTIP EFFECTS ON MOUSE-ENTER
                $('#myls'+i).animate(  {opacity:1 },100);
                 $('.chart-tooltip[data-index='+i+']').addClass('hover');
        // Add hover class to the targeted point
    }).on("mouseleave", function(d, i) {
//REMOVE TOOLTIP EFFECT ON MOUSE-LEAVE
            $('#myls'+i).animate(  {opacity:0 },100);
            $('.chart-tooltip').removeClass('hover');
            // Remove hover class from the targeted point

        });
```

This may not be the most efficient way but hope it helps.

Comment: this works without use of transition function too. Is it really essential to use transition function it if we re-render the rectangles?

Comment: Also if your rectangles have a class you can just use selectAll('.class') to get your entire set of rectangles and proceed as you wish.